# Reference Refusing to resolve

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload a file using asp.net core 2 and mvc however I have some code which No matter what I do will not resolve to system.web as I am using the that will not resolve sorry if this is really simple I am new to asp.net comming from a webforms background.

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
        if (file != null)
        {
            string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                                   Server.MapPath("~/images/profile"), pic);
            // file is uploaded
            file.SaveAs(path);

            // save the image path path to the database or you can send image 
            // directly to database
            // in-case if you want to store byte[] ie. for DB
            using (MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
            }

        }
        // after successfully uploading redirect the user
        return RedirectToAction("actionname", "controller name");
}
```

Server is not resolved nore is httpPostedFileBase but are these not just standard methods in System.Web anymore

These are my existing references

[image]

Comment: You should use IFormFile in asp.net core. See this [How to upload files in asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379309/how-to-upload-files-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: You are using .NET core so `System.Web` does not exist there. For your file use `IFormFile` beeing part of the ASP.NET Core implementation.

Comment: Do you still use the type file input

Comment: What reference do i need for IfromFile its not resolving