# How to convert filepath to a Uri

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to save file in my localdb how to convert fileName to absolute uri & pass  it to my setImage Method

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task <IActionResult> UploadNewImage(IFormFile file, string title, string tags)
    {
        var content = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);
        var fileName = content.FileName.Trim('"');

        await _imageService.SetImage(title, tags, uri);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Gallery");
    }
```

Here is my SetImage method

```
public async Task SetImage(string title, string tags, Uri uri)
    {
        var image = new GalleryImage
        {
            Title = title,
            Tags = ParseTags(tags),
            Url = uri.AbsolutePath,
            Created = DateTime.Now
        };
        _ctx.Add(image);
        await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I suggest not storing the absolute uri in table. Just store the unique file name so that the absolute uri can be built later when you want to. What if tomorrow your business decide to change the site base url from `thefacebook` to `facebook` ?

Comment: Also your code is not storing the image anywhere! Refer this [How to upload files in asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379309/how-to-upload-files-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public async Task SetImage(string title, string tags, Uri uri)
{
    var image = new GalleryImage
    {
        Title = title,
        Tags = ParseTags(tags),
        Url = uri.AbsoluteUri,
        Created = DateTime.Now
    };
    _ctx.Add(image);
    await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```