# MVC Retrieve photo from database and display in view using Bootstrap cards

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I'm creating an Animal Shelter application and when someone looks at the animals, I have it displayed using bootstrap cards.  I don't know how to get the images to display though.  I'm very new to MVC and C# so I don't understand a lot of the answers that are posted online for this particular question.

Model:

```
public class Pet
{
    public int Pet_ID { get; set; }

    // Other properties

    public string Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowCats()
    {
        var cats = db.Pets.Where(c => c.Species_Type == Species_Type.Cat).ToList();
        return View(cats);
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="container">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="card col-md-3">
        <img class="center-block" src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Photo)" height="300" width="230" alt=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) />

        // other display tags
    </div>
}
```

Create() - This is how I get the image from upload

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Pet upload, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), guid + fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                string fl = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\"));
                string[] split = fl.Split('\\');
                string newpath = split[1];
                string imagepath = "~/Uploads/" + newpath;
                upload.Photo = imagepath;
                db.Pets.Add(upload);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            TempData["Success"] = "Upload successful";

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I tried this method, but it interfered with my Create() because it couldn't convert string to byte (I changed my model from string Photo to byte[] Photo to try this particular way).

```
public ActionResult GetImage( int id )
{
     var photo = (new ApplicationDbContext()).Pets.Find(id).Photo;

    return File( imageData, "image/jpg" );
}
```

this was the View for it:

```
<img class="center-block" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Pet", new { id = item.Pet_ID })" height="300" width="230" alt=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) />
```

Comment: Do not store `~/Uploads/` in `imagepath ` when you store it in the table. Just store the unique file name. and then use that to set the image src

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example of what you're mentioning?  I just found this code source for uploading files, so I'm not sure how exactly I could change it.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379309/how-to-upload-files-in-asp-net-core/35385472#35385472 . It is for the asp.net core. But generating the unique file name and location is applicable for non-core code as well.