# Add a picture in a dotnet core model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor, .net-core

I have a dotnet core (+razor +ef) application with the usual model of a `Product` :-)

A product should have a picture associated, uploaded from the `Products\Create.cshtml` and `Products\Edit.cshtml` pages, stored in a table of the DB, and showed in the `Products\Details.cshtml`.

My model is something like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

First question: is it correct the use of `byte[]` for the picture?

Second question: since I guess I cannot automatically scaffolding the CRUD pages for a picture, how can I upload the image from the razor `Create.cshtml` page?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This seems a little like a homework question. Can you tell us what you have tried so far? Take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a few pointers.

Comment: It's not a homework, really. I have 20+ years of experience in professional programming (and with SO too :-). Unfortunately, I'm pretty new with .net technology, and the dotnet core documentation sucks :-) I've tried, but I couldn't really find help online about moving pictures from html page to DB and viceversa.

Comment: @DanielePallastrelli, you can [use this to upload file in .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35379309/3394380) and store just file path in database instead of `byte[]`

Comment: @yW0K5o unfortunately, I have to store the whole image into a table of the DB. It's a constraint of my application because another app will use the same DB to retrieve the pictures.

Comment: @DanielePallastrelli, [read this to save picture in database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5613926/3394380) and use my previous link how to upload file in .Net Core.

Comment: How is the size of the images ?

Comment: about 20-30 KBytes :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your `View` you can

1) Either go with embedded image bytes:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image)" />
```

2) Or - use the separate controller action like `GetImage` below, which returns the file:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", new { productId = Model.Id })" />
```

In this case you will need an additional controller action like this:

```
[HttpGet] 
public FileStreamResult GetImage(Guid productId) 
{ 
    using (var dbContext = new DbContext()) 
    { 
        var product = dbContext.Product.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == productId); 
        var ms = new MemoryStream(product.Image); 
        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/jpeg"); 
    } 
}
```

NOTE: if the images are not too big, storing them in DB might be OK. If not - I would suggest to consider storing them on file system (or in cloud storage) with metadata (like file name, etc.) in your database. But that is a different story for sure.